# Passing argument to struct

Tags: c++, stl, struct

I want to define a struct as follows:

```
struct myStruct {
   std::vector<double> myVector(vector_size, init_value);
   ...
}
```

Is it possible to pass the arguments `vector_size` (int), and `init_value` (double) to the struct?

Comment: You have a struct with a member function `myVector` returning a vector. Is this what you want?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. myVector is a stl vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a constructor for the struct:

```
struct myStruct {
   std::vector<double> myVector;

   myStruct(size_t vector_size, double init_value) : myVector(vector_size, init_value) {}
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Define a two argument constructor and use constructor initializer list:

```
struct myStruct{
   myStruct(size_t a_size, double a_value): myVector(a_size, a_value) {}
   std::vector<double> myVector;
};
```

Or, use [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) (see http://ideone.com/Ky50Ex):

```
struct myStruct
{
    std::vector<double> myVector;
};

myStruct m = { std::vector<double>(14, 0.5) };
```